# Receiving n topic updates, where n = 1+number of closed subscription to that topic

Tags: push-diffusion

My JavaScript client subscribes to a topic. If I unsubscribe and then resubscribe, then for every update on the topic I get a two updates delivered to the client.

Actually, for every subscription-unsubscription pair made I receive one more update when the topic is changed, so long as there is a current subscription.

e.g.

- Subscribe to `topic/a`
- `topic/a` changes & **one** update is delivered
- Unsubscribe to topic/a
- `topic/a` changes & no update is delivered
- Subscribe to `topic/a`
- `topic/a` changes & **two** updates are delivered
- Unsubscribe to topic/a
- `topic/a` changes & no update is delivered
- Subscribe to `topic/a`
- `topic/a` changes & **three** updates are delivered

How can I get only one notification per update?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you subscribe, the client uses a [Subscription Stream](http://docs.pushtechnology.com/docs/5.7.4/js/Subscription.html) to listen for different events. The events that we are interested in are the `update` and `unsubscribe` events. When you subscribe you are automatically telling the stream to listen for `update` events.

If you subscribe more than once, depending on how you have done this you may create multiple streams, each of which will receive `update` events.

For example the following opens two streams:

```
subscription = session.subscribe('test/topic').transform(String)
    .on('update', function(value, topicName) {
        console.log('Got update for topic: ' + topicName, value);
    });

subscription2 = session.subscribe('test/topic').transform(String)
    .on('update', function(value, topicName) {
        console.log('Got update for topic: ' + topicName, value);
    });
```

While the following only opens one stream:

```
subscription = session.subscribe('test/topic').transform(String)
    .on('update', function(value, topicName) {
        console.log('Got update for topic: ' + topicName, value);
    });

session.unsubscribe('test/topic');
session.subscribe('test/topic');
```

When the client unsubscribes to a topic all of the streams for that topic no longer listen for `update` events. However, if the client subscribes again, all of the streams for the topic will listen for `update` events again.

It is possible to close the stream when you unsubscribe so that it does not listen for updates when you `subscribe` again. This is achieved by listening for the `unsubscribe` event on the stream and calling [close()](http://docs.pushtechnology.com/docs/5.7.4/js/Subscription.html#close) on the stream from within it.

For example:

```
subscription = session.subscribe('test/topic').transform(String)
    .on('update', function(value, topicName) {
        console.log('Got update for topic: ' + topicName, value);
    });

subscription.on('unsubscribe', function(reason, topic) {
    console.log('Unsubscribed from topic:' + topic);
    subscription.close();
});

subscription2 = session.subscribe('test/topic').transform(String)
    .on('update', function(value, topicName) {
        console.log('Got update for topic: ' + topicName, value);
    });

session.unsubscribe('test/topic');
session.subscribe('test/topic');
```

In this example, when `unsubscribe` is called `subscription` is closed. When `subscribe` is subsequently called only subscription2 listens for updates.

This code can also be expressed more succinctly using object literals:

```
subscription = session.subscribe('test/topic').transform(String).on({
    update : function(update, topic) {
        console.log('Got update for topic: ' + topic, update);
    },
    unsubscribe : function(reason, topic) {
        console.log('Unsubscribed from : ' + topic);
        subscription.close();
    }
});

subscription2 = session.subscribe('test/topic').transform(String).on({
    update : function(update, topic) {
        console.log('Got update for topic: ' + topic, update);
    }
});

session.unsubscribe('test/topic');
session.subscribe('test/topic');
```